# UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath is not being called

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I have been working on a launch database for SpaceX and I have successfully parsed my data but the function to create and add the data to the cell is not working. I have added the delegates and data sources but I still cannot find out why it won't run.

```
import UIKit

struct launchData : Decodable
{
    let flight_number : Int
    let launch_date_utc : String

    struct rocketInfo : Decodable
    {
        let rocket_name : String
    }

    let rocket : rocketInfo
}

class LaunchViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var launchTableView: UITableView!

    var arrayOfLaunchData:[launchData] = []

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.launchTableView.delegate = self
        self.launchTableView.dataSource = self

        getJsonData()

        self.launchTableView.reloadData()
    }

    func getJsonData()
    {
        let jsonUrlString = "https://api.spacexdata.com/v2/launches"
        guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else { return }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in

            guard let data = data else { return }

            do {
                let launchDataDecoded = try JSONDecoder().decode([launchData].self, from: data)
                print(launchDataDecoded)
            } catch let jsonErr {
                print("Error Serialization json:", jsonErr )
            }
        }.resume()
        print("getJsonData ran")
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("")
        print(arrayOfLaunchData.count)
        print("")
        print("TableView number of rows ran")

        return arrayOfLaunchData.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellID")

        let launch = self.arrayOfLaunchData[indexPath.row]

        let flightNumber = launch.flight_number
        let rocketName = launch.rocket.rocket_name

        cell?.textLabel?.text = "Mission " + String(flightNumber)

        let launchDate = launch.launch_date_utc
        cell!.detailTextLabel!.text = "Launch Date: " + launchDate + "Rocket Used: " + rocketName

        self.launchTableView.reloadData()

        print("TableView cellForRowAt ran")
        return cell!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all **never** call  `reloadData()` in `cellForRowAt`! Delete the line

Two major issues:

1. `reloadData()` is called too soon.
2. The data source array is not populated after receiving the data.

The solution is to delete the line

```
self.launchTableView.reloadData()
```

(also) in `viewDidLoad()` and change `getJsonData()` to

```
func getJsonData()
{
    let jsonUrlString = "https://api.spacexdata.com/v2/launches"
    guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else { return }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in

        guard let data = data else { return }

        do {
            self.arrayOfLaunchData = try JSONDecoder().decode([launchData].self, from: data)
            print(launchDataDecoded)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.launchTableView.reloadData()
            }

        } catch  {
            print("Error Serialization json:", error )
        }

   }.resume()
   print("getJsonData ran")

}
```

because `dataTask` works asynchronously.

Note:

Please conform to the naming convention that struct and class names start with a capital letter (`LaunchData`, `RocketInfo`) and all names are supposed to be *camelCased* rather than *snake_cased*.

Answer (score 1):

Remove **self.launchTableView.reloadData()** from **viewDidLoad()**

and put on getting successfully data

```
do {
            let launchDataDecoded = try JSONDecoder().decode([launchData].self, from: data)
            print(launchDataDecoded)
            self.launchTableView.reloadData()
        } catch let jsonErr {
            print("Error Serialization json:", jsonErr )
        }
    }.resume()
```

**getJsonData()** is follow asynchronous. hope this help!